# Is it possible to reverse an internal transaction?

Tags: go-ethereum

I've been reading about internal vs normal transactions, and since internal transactions are not recorded on the blockchain, isn't it possible to reverse them by changing the state of a contract after the transaction is complete?

Example:

imagine TokenA has a blacklist

0xff..aa trades 10,000 TokenA for .1 ETH on uniswap

After transaction is complete, TokenA adds 0xff..aa to their blacklist

wouldn't that invalidate the uniswap trade, and reverse the .1 ETH back to uniswap, and prevent 0xff..aa from selling their TokenA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the contract state after any transaction, you will need another transaction - the contract state itself will not change.
As for the consequences of being blacklisted, it is entirely determined by the implementation of the corresponding method in your contract - it can leave previous transactions unchanged or cancel them.

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you're saying is, the uniswap router would need to reference the blacklist in order for the internal transaction to be reversed? just as a general example, if Tether blacklists an address, would the uniswap transactions for that address involving USDT be reversed?

Comment: I do not know how this is specifically implemented in uniswap - I have shown the technical ability to implement this feature. How this should be done specifically at the contract or exchange level depends on the specifics of your business case.